# Adding space between button and component on same horizontal row

Tags: material-ui

I have a button and a CircularProgress component that are next to each other on the same row. I want to add a little bit of space between them. How can I achieve this? I've been trying using style etc but failing.

```
<Grid
  container
  direction="row"
  // justify="space-between"
  spacing={50}
>
  <Button
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    size="large"
    style={{ marginTop: '1em' }}
    // style={{ maxWidth: '108px', minWidth: '108px' }}
    onClick={() => {
      //code
    }}
  >
    Import Games
  </Button>
  {showCircularProgress === true ? (
    <CircularProgress style={{ marginTop: '1em' }} />
  ) : (
    ''
  )}
</Grid>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For that you would need to use `marginRight` to the direction of you next element**

```
<Grid container direction="row">
  <Button
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    size="large"
    style={{ marginRight: "32px" }}
  >
    Import Games
  </Button>
  <CircularProgress style={{ marginTop: "1em" }} />
</Grid>;
```

You could read more about CSS margin [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

Simplified Working Example:

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]